# No such file or directory error in flutter_ffmpeg

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I intend to use the flutter_ffmpeg package to convert audio to video with the image as a background, but I am encountering a very weird error. Despite the fact that the files exist in the location that I have provided to the flutter_ffmpeg package as input, I am getting a 'No such file or directory' error. I have already tested out everything I can thnk of but I just don't get it.

```
Future<String> converter(String audioPath, String imagePath) async {
String? videoPath;
Directory? dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
// videoPath = dir!.path;
final videoDirectory = '${dir!.path}/VDir';
if (await Directory(videoDirectory).exists() == false) {
  await Directory(videoDirectory).create();
}
// await Directory(videoDirectory).create();
videoPath = videoDirectory + '/${DateTime.now().millisecond}.mp4';
print(
    "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
print("\nAudioPath = " + audioPath);
print("\nImagePath = " + imagePath);
print("\nVideoPath = " + videoPath);
print("\nVideoDirectory = " + videoDirectory);
print(
    "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
_flutterFFmpeg
    .execute(
        '-loop 1 -framerate 2 -i \'$imagePath\' -i \'$audioPath\' -vf "scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2),setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p $videoPath')
    .catchError((onError) {
  print(onError);
  // ErrorHandler().errorDialog(context, )
});
return videoPath;}
```

`videoPath = await FFmpegOperations().converter(widget.audioPath, coverImagePath);`

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code, I am using the min-gpl version(not lts) ffmpeg and am testing this on two android devices I am getting the same results.

Error:
/data/user/0/com.example.example/app_flutter/datte.png: No such file or directory
D/flutter-ffmpeg( 1139): FFmpeg exited with rc: 1
.
Any form of help would be more than welcome, thank you.

Comment: Who put the files in those directories? Android version of used devices?

Comment: `data/user/0/com.example.example/app_flutter/datte.png` That does not very much look like using `await getExternalStorageDirectory();`.

Comment: I was using getApplicationStorageDirectory() to get a place to save image using imagePath, you are confusing the value of string videoPath and value of String imagePath, see clearly. I saved those files in those directories, after performing some operations.